# How to billboard game sprites based on camera angle?

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor, shaders, camera

So to keep things simple, here is a sphere with a blue and green line going through it for reference:

[image]

Here is a sprite sheet with roughly the same angles portraying the 3d sphere:

[image]

My question is, how do I change sprites based on the camera angle in the scene to match that of its 3d counterpart?

I have successfully learnt how to use the lock track object constraint, but how would I go about actually changing the sprites as well?

Here is my character front on with lock tracked object constraints for all the limbs.
[image]

But when I turn the camera i want his eyes to be facing forwards by using a different sprite (he shouldnt still be looking at the camera):

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!